# Select Statement for 2 Tables

Tags: sql-server

Hello everyone i have create 2 table in my SQL SERVER, the first table is called auction, the second bid, each auction has a status, they can be either valid, expired or unsold, when a auction is unsold, it does not have any bid, but when expired the auction should have one or bid, the problem is that i want to select every auction that has a bid and named it as successful and all auction which has status unsold as unsuccessful

here is my code

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, BID.Date) AS Years
      ,COUNT(DATENAME(Month, BID.Date)) AS Total 
  FROM Auction 
       INNER JOIN 
       BID ON Auction.AuctionID = BID.AuctionID 
       INNER JOIN  
       Item ON Auction.ItemID = Item.ItemID 
 WHERE (Auction.Status = 'Expired') 
   AND (BID.Status = 'Won') 
 GROUP BY DATENAME(month, BID.Date)

SELECT DATENAME(month, BID.Date) AS Years
     , COUNT(DATENAME(Month, BID.Date)) AS Total 
  FROM Auction 
       INNER JOIN 
       BID ON Auction.AuctionID = BID.AuctionID 
       INNER JOIN  
       Item ON Auction.ItemID = Item.ItemID 
 WHERE (Auction.Status = 'UnSold') 
 GROUP BY DATENAME(month, BID.Date)
```

I want to group them by date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure I understand exactly what you asking. Maybe if you posted some sample data and a mock up the results set you want it would be easier.

Still, I think the key is you need to know the "result" (sold/unsold) of each auction. That can be done a few different ways, but Here's a relatively straightforward option to get you started

```
SELECT AuctionID
      ,ItemId
      ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                          FROM BID 
                         WHERE BID.AuctionID=Auction.AuctionID) 
            THEN 'Won'
            ELSE 'UnSold'
       END Status
  FROM Auction
```

EDIT:

One way to then get total would be to use something like the above as a CTE:

```
WITH AuctionResult AS (
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                             FROM BID 
                            WHERE BID.AuctionID=Auction.AuctionID) 
                THEN 'Won'
                ELSE 'UnSold'
           END [Status]
      FROM Auction 
) SELECT [Status]
        ,COUNT(*)
    FROM AuctionResult
   GROUP BY [Statush
```

Comment: you are not far but if i want to have the total of won and the the total of unsold how would it be please>

Comment: Just the count of item sold vs item not sold? All you have to do is re-query that result set grouping on status. There are multiple ways.